# Calcular los días de la semana que hay en un intervalo determinado de fechas

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Tengo que hacer un código en `swift` que:

1. Calcule los días que han transcurrido entre dos fechas.
2. Calcule cuantos días de la semana hay en ese intervalo.

**Ejemplo:**

> Cuantos miércoles hay entre el 10-11-2016 y el 25-12-2016

La primera parte para calcular los días transcurridos los tengo, pero la segunda no.

Mi código:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

let strDateDesde = yearDesde + "-" + monthDesde + "-" + dayDesde + " " + arrayFechaDesde[1]
let strDateHasta = yearHasta + "-" + monthHasta + "-" + dayHasta + " " + arrayFechaHasta[1]

//print(strDateDesde)

let dateDesde = dateFormatter.date(from: strDateDesde)
let dateHasta = dateFormatter.date(from: strDateHasta)

let fDesde = calendar.startOfDay(for: dateDesde!)
let fHasta = calendar.startOfDay(for: dateHasta!)

let numeroDias = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: fDesde, to: fHasta).day!
```

Comment: no entiendo lo de "Calcule cuantos dias de la semana hay en ese intervalo"

Comment: Ejemplo: `Cuantos mièrcoles hay entre el 10-11-2016 y el 25-12-2016` @lois6b

Comment: aaah okk , entiendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado ésta función que creo que es exactamente lo que estás buscando:

```
func numberOfWednesdaysBeetweenDates(startDate startDate:NSDate,endDate:NSDate)->Int{
    var count = 0
    let oneDay = NSDateComponents()
    oneDay.day = 1;
    // Usando el calendario Gregoriano.
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var currentDate = startDate;

    while (currentDate.compare(endDate) != .OrderedDescending) {
       let dateComponents = calendar.components(.Weekday, fromDate: currentDate)
        if (dateComponents.weekday == 4){
            count++;
        }
        // Incrementamos en 1 la fecha actual
        currentDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(oneDay, toDate: currentDate, options: [])!
    }
    return count
}
```

Te sirve para calcular el número de días de la semana que indiques. Si pones por ejemplo, `if (dateComponents.weekday == 4 || dateComponents.weekday == 5)` te calcula cuántos miércoles y jueves hay.

Comment: Gracias, funciona bien, pero una cosa, el dia de la semana comienza en domingo, por lo que el `3 = martes y el 4 = miercoles`

Comment: Si, tienes razón. Actualizo la respuesta. Un saludo